# Can I do math within a LESS css string interpolation?

Tags: css, less, interpolation

I have this less and I can't figure out how to do the math inside the string

```
@bp-tablet-landscape: 1024px; 
@bp-tablet-portrait : 768px;
@tablet-landscape-only: ~"only screen and 
 (min-width:@{bp-tablet-portrait} + 1) and (max-width: @{bp-tablet-landscape})";
```

Usage

```
div#header {

 @media @tablet-landscape-only {
      background: #000; 
 }
}
```

But it doesn't quite compile correctly. It doesn't add 768px + 1 as I had hoped. Any ideas? I've tried several different flavors and I can't nail it.  I can obviously define a variable outside the string concat, but I'd like to avoid that approach if possible.

[winLess online compiler](http://winless.org/online-less-compiler) outputs

```
@media only screen and (min-width:768px + 1) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  div#header {
   background: #000;
  }
}
```

I want to get `769px` in there instead of `768px + 1`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Not Within the String Itself, but...

If you separate it out of the string, then do a second interpolation following (note the 2nd `~`), this works:

```
@tablet-landscape-only: ~"only screen and (min-width: "(@bp-tablet-portrait + 1) ~") and (max-width: @{bp-tablet-landscape})";
```

To produce this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:  769px ) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  div#header {
    background: #000;
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this is the solution I was looking for!

Comment: Awesome indeed! But do you realize that the output css has empty spaces? I'm not sure about this but I guess this is an issue for Internet Explorer.

Comment: The key here is the parenthesis around the calculation

Comment: 2022 and here I am, thank you Magento