# Perform calculations in escaped LESS

Tags: less

I'm currently using LESS variables and the `~` escape method to define certain media queries like this:

```
@threeColumns:   ~"only screen and (min-width: 855px)";
```

However, what I'd ideally like to do is define the min-width value with a calculation of another LESS variable. I know you can use variables in escaped LESS like this:

```
@columnWidth: 265px;
@threeColumns:   ~"only screen and (min-width: @{columnWidth})";
```

But can you multiply these variables within the the escaped bit of LESS. This work something like this (*not valid LESS*):

```
@columnWidth: 265px;
@threeColumns:   ~"only screen and (min-width: (@{columnWidth}*2) )";
```

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819699/can-i-do-math-within-a-less-css-string-interpolation

Comment: I just answered practically the same question yesterday (there it was addition, not multiplication), which is the question linked to in the comment above.